# mod_rewrite: how to handle a url within the query string?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an URL like this:
`http://www.domain.tld/index.php?url=http://www.otherdomain.tld`

Now I want to use mod_rewrite so that this url is rewritten to an url as mentioned above:
`http://www.domain.tld/check/http://www.otherdomain.tld`

I also tried it url_encoded:
`http://www.domain.tld/check/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.otherdomain.tld`

Both version do not work. I always get an 404 error saying
`The requested URL /check/http://www.otherdomain.tld was not found on this server.`

I'm absolutely new to mod_rewrite and tried the following rule:
`RewriteRule check/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1`
which works for any non-url-like parameter (e.g. `test`), but not for URL-like parameters.

Any help is appreciated to fix this rule.

Thanks in advance.

Marc

Comment: If the characters are not urlencoded, that would constitute an illegal URL and fail to be parsed properly.

Comment: Yes, that's why I urlencoded the part. But it still doesn't work...

Comment: Have you tried keeping the rule in to pass to `index.php` but getting the value out of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?  When using a Front Controller in a PHP project, it's usually a lot easier to process the URL in PHP, rather than getting mod_rewrite to deal with it.

Comment: I do not get so far to check the URL in PHP:
The RewriteRule is defined within a htaccess file which also includes a definition for a 404 page.
If I enter the url `http://www.domain.tld/check/test` I can see the page I defined. But if I enter `http://www.domain.tld/check/http%3A%2F%2Ftest` I get a 404 page, but not the one I defined (which works in general) but a default page from the server. That also happens if I change the RewriteRule to only call index.php without parameters.
The Rewrite log does not have any entries for this attempt - it looks like it breaks earlier...

Comment: @zotto: Must be something in the server handling of the URL that says it is invalid - can you not trim the `https://` bit ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you enable Mod rewrite on your server?
2. Did you write "RewriteEngine On" before that rule?
   Your htaccess file should look like this:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule check/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1

To check if mod_rewrite is not enabled on your Apache server, just enter some random stuff in your .htaccess file as it should break all that website.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled and the rule basically works already with e.g. `http://www.domain.tld/check/test` but not with an URL as query parameter.